# Android studio:Configure Project in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz

> Configure project :app
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz\app\google-services.json
>
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
>
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
>   C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
>       activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz\app\src\main\res\drawable\btntrail.xml"}],"original":"C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz\app\src\main\res\drawable\btntrail.xml: AAPT: error:  elements require a sdk version of at least 26.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource linking failed
  >    C:\Users\Zebranic\AndroidStudioProjects\Atoz\app\src\main\res\drawable\btntrail.xml: AAPT: error:  elements require a sdk version of at least 26.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed

Comment: Can you post your App level build.gradle file?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vasantham.infotech.atoz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: You can edit the question again and add it below the question.

Comment: I tried in 2days but still i can't get result so pls solve me this.

Comment: have you bumped up your target SDK version in recent days?

Answer (score 0):

**AAPT: error: elements require a sdk version of at least 26.\n ","tool":"AAPT"**

Try Updating SDK version.

Settings->System Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tools

Check Android SDK Tools 26.1.1

At least **v26** is to be installed or higher.

Comment: I installed upto v28

Comment: R 1 Not installed
  29 4 Partially installed
  28 6 Installed
  27 3 Installed
  26 2 Installed
  25 3 Installed
  24 2 Installed
  23 3 Installed
  22 2 Not installed
  21 2 Installed
  20 2 Not installed

Comment: Are telling about SDK tools or SDK Platforms